# Java CompareTo Method

Tags: java, compareto

I wrote some code for a problem assigned to us, and my current code keeps giving me the wrong outputs. The prompt for the question is as follows:

As some of you may know, there is no name better than JOHN. Let's define the rules for comparing names. Each letter has a weight ('A' - 1, 'B' - 2, ..., 'Z' - 26). The weight of a name is the sum of the weights of all its letters. For example, the name MARK has weight 13 + 1 + 18 + 11 = 43.
When comparing two names, the one with the larger weight is considered better. In case of a tie, the one that comes earlier lexicographically is better. But there is one exception - the name JOHN is the best name of all.
You are given a String[] names, each element of which contains a single name. Sort the names from best to worst and return the sorted String[].

The code I wrote is as follows:

```
public class TheBestName {
        public String[] sort(String[] names) {
            Arrays.sort(names, new APTComp());
            return names;
        }

        class APTComp implements Comparator<String>{
            public int compare(String a,String b){
                String alphabet= "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
                HashMap<Character,Integer> greatMap = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
                for(int i=0;i<alphabet.length();i++){
                    greatMap.put(alphabet.charAt(i), i+1);
                }
                int countA=0;
                int countB=0;
                for(int i=0;i<a.length();i++){
                    int temp= greatMap.get(a.charAt(i));
                    countA+= temp;
                }
                for(int i=0;i<b.length();i++){
                    int temp=greatMap.get(b.charAt(i));
                    countB+=temp;
                }
                if(a.equals("JOHN") && b.equals("JOHN")){
                    return 0;
                }
                if(a.equals("JOHN") && !b.equals("JOHN")){
                    return 1;
                }
                if(!a.equals("JOHN") && b.equals("JOHN")){
                    return -1;
                }
                else{
                    int diff= countA-countB;
                    if(diff!=0){
                        return diff;
                    }
                    if(diff==0){
                        return a.compareTo(b);
                    }

                }
            }

        }



    }
```

It appears as though I get the reverse of what I should be getting in most cases. I tried fiddling around with the compareTo method, but it didn't make a difference. Can you guys please tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Junaid

Comment: I'm *confused*, why not `return a.compareTo(b);`? Also, you might try my [ComparableComparator](http://www.frischcode.com/2013/11/help-i-have-comparable-but-i-need.html)

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it,

```
     public int compare(String a, String b) {
        String alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
        HashMap<Character, Integer> greatMap = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < alphabet.length(); i++) {
            greatMap.put(alphabet.charAt(i), i + 1);
        }
        int countA = 0;
        int countB = 0;

        if (a.equals("JOHN")) {
            countA = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
                int temp = greatMap.get(a.charAt(i));
                countA += temp;
            }
        }
        if (b.equals("JOHN")) {
            countB = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < b.length(); i++) {
                int temp = greatMap.get(b.charAt(i));
                countB += temp;
            }
        }

        if (countB == countA) {
            return a.compareTo(b);
        }

        return countB - countA;

    }
```

Comment: that is fine because he has return statement

Comment: I had a question. Why are you returning count B- count A, and not count A - countB?

Comment: @user2904796 it depends on what you define as 'greater than', and if in the end you want your list to end up sorted with what you call 'greater' first or last